# NHibernate Relations vs. Query Performance

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've the following situation:

- I've got a large Database Model with a lot of Relations

Now my Problem is, that i would like to generate the Relations in the Mappings, because that would simplify my insert and update logic. But if I have the Relations in the mappings I run in an performance issue. Which is logical for me, because too much data got loaded.

Now I'm looking for a way how I can solve this Problem.
Is it possible to specify the Relation Mapping without loading the data or to decide in the query whitch relation should load.
Is there a way in NHibernate to achieve this goal?

I could not lazy load the Relations because the DataAccess is called over WCF and therefore the session gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

Logically if you want to fetch a lot of data, you should use a query (probably a query over,HQL or Linq) and then use custom DTO to pass data back to your service.

When you do the update most of the time limited amount of data is updated, then you can fetch the entity to be updated set the relevant fields and commit the transaction. It's not a great idea to sent entities over services when it comes to large lists (for example a search screen) but to map it to a simple DTOwith exact info displayed in screen and sent back.